# Using --exclude with the du command

Tags: command-line, disk-usage

This is probably something basic but I'm not able to make it work. I'm trying to use DU to get a total size of files minus certain directories. I need to exclude one specific directory called `uploads` but not every directory called `uploads`. For example, my file structure looks a bit like this:

```
/store
  /uploads
    /junk_to_ignore
    /more_junk_to_ignore
  /user_one
    /uploads
  /user_two
```

I can run the following command:

```
du -ch --exclude=uploads*
```

and it gives me the file size minus all the "uploads" directories. However, in trying to exclude certain directories (and all its sub-directories) I fail. I've tried variations of:

```
du -ch --exclude=./uploads*
du -ch --exclude='/full/path/to/uploads/*'
```

but can't seem to figure it out. How do I exclude a specific directory?

Comment: `username: store$ du -ch --exclude=./uploads` worked (with and without the wildcard) for me, from within the store directory.  Are you running that command exactly and from within the store folder? And it has to be the relative path (that find sees/prints), not absolute.

Answer (score 163, accepted):

You've almost found it :)

```
du -ch --exclude=./relative/path/to/uploads
```

Note **no** asterisk at the end. The asterisk means all *subdirectories under "upload"* should be omitted - but not the files directly in that directory.

Comment: Strange... syntax with dot (`du -sb --exclude=./relative/path/to/uploads`) doesn't work for me. This does: `du -sb --exclude relative/path/to/uploads`

Comment: @Nux probably your flavor of `du`. Mine (OSX) doesn't even have `--exclude`, instead it has `-I mask` to "Ignore files and directories matching the specified mask." In your working example you also omit the `=`, making me further think it's just your version of `du` being slightly `du`fferent.

Comment: Yes [OSX][1] version seems quite more simplified version of [Linux du][2].

  [1]: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/du.1.html
  [2]: http://linux.die.net/man/1/du

Comment: What if I want to exclude multiple directories for example here excluding directories junk_to_ignore and uploads directories?

Comment: Why does it work with a relative path, but not an absolute path? Very odd!

Comment: Doesn't work either. I tr to use it with `du -hs *`

Comment: is there an example of how to use the `-I` flag which the macOS / OS X version has? Its not working with any syntax shown here, nor `du -sh -I demo/` style syntax

Answer (score 30):

To exclude multiple directories, just pass the --exclude flag again.

```
du -ch --exclude=relative/path/to/uploads --exclude other/path/to/exclude
```

Comment: you ca also use `du -ch --exclude={relative/path/to/uploads,other/path/to/exclude}`

Answer (score 20):

Awesome, to skip the virtual file systems do this:

```
du -hsx --exclude=/{proc,sys,dev,run} /*
```

Answer (score 8):

To exclude multiple folders

```
du -ch --exclude={path/to/folder1,path/to_folder2/,...,}
```

Comment: hi, what if we want to exclude all sub-folder? only count files that direct children to current directory.

Answer (score 6):

If you have to be on macOS, you install GNU Coreutils with the following command.

```
brew install coreutils
```

Most of the commands installed by Coreutils are prefixed by `g`, since they have a BSD namesake preinstalled on macOS.  Then you can do the following.

```
gdu --exclude=Microsoft /Library/Fonts/
```

Answer (score 5):

Just adding a Mac example

```
du -skI "Downloads" -I "Caches" -I "Logs" -I "OneDrive" .
```

I do not see a way to use the `-I` with a path, so for example, I haven't gotten

```
du -skI "Downloads" -I "Caches" -I "Logs" -I "OneDrive" -I "Library/Application Support"  .
```

to work. May be possible, but I haven't gotten it yet.

Answer (score -1):

To get the total size of files in `files/` excluding all sub-directories

`du -ch path/to/files --exclude=path/to/files/*/*`