# How to apply du (f.x.) to all sub directories except for some of them?

Tags: disk-usage

```
./a
 |-/bx1
 |-/by2
 |-/bz3
 |-/bx4
 |-/by5
```

Now I want to apply `du` to all sub-folders except for /by2 and /bx4.

I can make it happen for one folder:

```
du --max-depth=1 --exclude=./by2
```

but not for two.

---

I found to related questions:

1. [Getting size of directories and exclude some folders](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/102879/getting-size-of-directories-and-exclude-some-folders)
2. [Using --exclude with the du command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23692/using-exclude-with-the-du-command)

In (1) regular expressions are applied which won't work in my case - at least not comfortably. In (2) the exclusion refers to a full sub-directory. Essentially my question is:

Can I feed `--exclude` a list of files/directories and if yes, how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
du --max-depth=1 --exclude=./by2 --exclude=./bx4 ./a
```